# Best web scraping Ruby on Rails library that handles dynamic HTML produced by javascript

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, rubygems, web-scraping

I am using Ruby on Rails with the Mechanize library to scrape store websites.  The problem is that many times I can't crawl certain elements.  However, I can see this when I 'view source' on the site.

For example, Walmart's category (in this case below it is "Health") is unscapeable. I believe this is because it is dynamically produced HTML (e.g. from javascript).  In order to scrape this, I need a browser to process the web request.

http://www.walmart.com/ip/Replacement-Sensor-Module-for-AlcoMate-Prestige-Breathalyzer/10167376

I am also using a linux machine on Amazon EC2.  It would be tough to install browser for UI scraping. Is there any Rails gem/plugin that can help me?

Thanks, all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, rephrased, is, what's an easy way to parse an HTML document's [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model) in the same way a web browser would, then execute the JavaScript in the document against the parsed DOM? Without running an actual web browser.

That's a little tricky.

However, all is not lost. Take a look at [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). Though created for acceptance testing you can also use it for general grokking of documents. To execute JavaScript you'll need to use a driver that supports it, and since you want it to be "headless" (no browser GUI) that probably means using [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), [Akephalos](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos) or [capybara-envjs](https://github.com/smparkes/capybara-envjs).

Another option might be [Harmony](https://github.com/mynyml/harmony), which I know nothing about except that it appears to do what you want but also appears not to be maintained anymore, so YMMV.