# Java - Lottery statistic parser

Tags: java, javascript, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse some *int* s from a webpage and I have run into some problems:

**1**
The webpage is generated using javascript.

This sample code (Credz to Oracle.com. StackOverflow will not let me link) prints out the html code before the javascript is executed.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**Q:** How can I get the generated html?

**2** The webpage is not rendered rendered correctly when going directly to the link:
[This direct link](https://www.norsk-tipping.no/nt-keno/result/keno_result_info_print.jsp?drawID=1771&bet=10&keno_level=10) will render as an empty "shell".
Going to [this link](https://www.norsk-tipping.no/resultater/keno?NT.mc_id=nt-keno-resultat) and clicking **Vis utskriftsside** (Down to the left) will open a new correctly rendered window.

**Q:** What is the difference between the two links and how can I access the correctly rendered webpage using the direct link?

**EDIT**

This is the HTML/JavaScript generating the numbers I'm trying to scrape:

```
 <div id="drawNumbers" class="drawn-numbers">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var tableData ='';
    if (opener.draw_numbers) {
        for(var i = 0; i<opener.draw_numbers.length;i++){
            tableData += '<div class="number" style="left:'+(i*28+8)+'px;">';
            tableData += '<img width="23" height="23" alt="" src="/nt-keno/result/images/res_keno_tallramme_print.gif">';
            tableData += '</div>';
            tableData +=  '<div class="number" style="left:'+(i*28+9)+'px; top:9px; z-index: 30;">' +opener.draw_numbers[i]+ '</div>';
        }
    }
    document.writeln(tableData);
</script>
</div>
```

Can I import this array into java?

```
opener.draw_numbers[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page has a frame which contains:

https://www.norsk-tipping.no/nt-keno/result/keno_result_info.jsp?drawID=1771&bet=10&keno_level=10

The data comes from a json url. You can see this with tools such as firebug:

https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-keno/getResultInfo.json

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is termed 'scraping', where dynamic pages often cause problems:

[How do you scrape AJAX pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260540/how-do-you-screen-scrape-ajax-pages)

[Scraping dynamically generated html inside Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093130/scraping-dynamically-generated-html-inside-android-app)

[Best web scraping Ruby on Rails library that handles dynamic HTML produced by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484305/best-web-scraping-ruby-on-rails-library-that-handles-dynamic-html-produced-by-ja)

There are no simple solutions.

Comment: I assume the data I'm trying to access is stored in a database. Is it possible to find where it is stored?

Comment: @Bøtteknotten Unless you have the ability to query the database directly (or they make an API available), knowing where the database was located would not help.